# Unable to parse JSON data using beans in JAVA

Tags: java, json, eclipse

Here is my code for the parsing the JSON file and printing too.:

```
public class JsonpJsonParser implements IparseJson {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IparseJson parser = new JsonpJsonParser();
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("data.json")) {
        List<QueryResultBean1> results = parser.parseJson(in);
        for (QueryResultBean1 result : results) {
            System.out.println(result.getHeader().getRequest_id());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public List<QueryResultBean1> parseJson(InputStream in) {
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(in);
    JsonObject json = reader.readObject();
    reader.close();

    // parse the json object, return something
    List<QueryResultBean1> results = new ArrayList<QueryResultBean1>();
    JsonArray items = json.getJsonArray("header");
    for (JsonValue item : items) {
        if (item instanceof JsonObject) {
            QueryResultBean1 result = createBean((JsonObject)item);
            results.add(result);
        }
    }
    return results;
}


public QueryResultBean1 createBean(JsonObject json) {
    QueryResultBean1 bean = new QueryResultBean1();

    // you could also change tags to a List
    JsonArray array = json.getJsonArray("header");
    String[] h1 = new String[array.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
        h1[i] = array.getString(i);
    }
    bean.setTags(h1);
    retrun bean}
```

Ive tried executing this code for the JSON file:

```
"header":[  
  {  
     "request_id":1547706529870,
     "file_name":"Sm-1547706529870.xlsm",
     "file_type":"CIR",
     "status":"NEW",
     "is_end":false
  }
```

GOT THE ERROR AS:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat com.example.webjson.com.webjson.p1.JsonpJsonParser.createBean(JsonpJsonParser.java:60)

**NEED HELP TO PARSE THE DATA.JSON FILE IN JAVA**

Comment: Can you indicate which line is line 60 please ?

Comment: Which is line 60? `JsonArray array = json.getJsonArray("header");` this one?

Comment: I suspect the `"is_end":false` part. Can you try `"is_end":"false"`? (with double quotes around `false`).

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle that's ok bro..

Answer (score 0):

In the code below:

```
JsonArray array = json.getJsonArray("header");
```

You are trying to retrieve an JsonArray from String?, you should retrieve the element in array using an index like:

```
JsonArray array = json.getJsonArray(0);
```